# Switch language on Android device with bluetooth keyboard

Tags: keyboard, bluetooth, languages, external-keyboard

I'm using Logitech MK850 bluethooth keyboard and mouse combo on Samsung Galaxy S8+.
If I'm using Samsung (default) keyboard, I can switch language (Korean/English) using Kor/Eng switch key on the keyboard (it's actually right Alt key).
But I'm using Swiftkey (keyboard app.), this language switch key does not work. Shift + Space does not work either.

How can I switch language using the bluetooth keyboard?

Comment: Tried Ctrl+Shift' ?

Comment: Thank you for Shift+Space - it works for my Logitech G613

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to *Settings → Language and Input*, then find *Languages* and select *English* and your language.

Now you should be able to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> key combination to change languages from the Bluetooth physical keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings-> language and input and then click physical keyboard.  Now you can change language of your physical keyboard

Comment: It's not the answer. I'm using software keyboard when I type by 'fingers' but use hardware (bluethooth) keyboard only when I'm using bluethoose keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use some BT-aware helper application (for example, External Keyboard Helper (pro version it is not free, but there is a free demo in Google Play).

Answer (score 0):

On my Jademall Bluetooth keyboard connecting to an Android 11 A8, the key combination to change language is `SHIFT` + `SPACE`.