# How to add US international keyboard on Android?

Tags: samsung, keyboard, external-keyboard, android-13

I bought a Bluetooth QWERTY external keyboard for my Android tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab S8) running Android 13. But I need to make the French accent and special characters.

I know it's possible to put the US International keyboard option but unlike Windows, this keyboard layout doesn't exist in the parameters of Android devices.

Is there another way to install it?

Comment: Just making sure you've seen/tried: [cannot change languange on external keyboard](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/77538/3573) [Umlauts (Ö, Ü, Ä) on English US-International keyboards on Android with a physcial keyboard](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/242095/3573)and [Switch language on Android device with bluetooth keyboard](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/191663/3573) Please note that you were not clear if the external keyboard was USB or Bluetooth and the version of Android OS your tablet is running.

Comment: I edited my message to add the missing infos and yeah i read those topics, one is pointing to the us international keyboard layout that i know of but my problem is this layout doesn't exist on my device it seems

Comment: Welcome to the Q&A site Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. Possibly related/duplicate despite the title: [Romanian Layout for Physical Keyboard is absent](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/185124/44325); you probably need to install and test some 3rd-party external keyboard apps.